# Looped Module Return (Python 2.7.10)

Tags: python, loops, return

I stumbled across a fix for my problem, though I do not quite understand why it works. For reference, "users" refers to a dictionary { 'username' : 1234 } where "1234" is the User ID.

**First Attempt:**

```
users = users_found()


def target_user():
    for key in users.keys():
        print key

    target = raw_input("Which user do you want to target? ").lower()

    try:
        print users[target], target

        return users[target], target

    except KeyError:
        print "No such user was listed"

        target_user()


target, username = target_user()
```

The above did not work, against my better understanding and returned

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

referencing the very last line, of the variable assignment.

However, to check if 'target' was a 'NoneType' I inserted the print statement and this showed the values I was expecting even though the proceeding return seemed to be looking somewhere else using the same variables.

So *naturally* (really have no idea why) I tried a while loop instead.

**Second Attempt:**

```
users = users_found()

def target_user():
    for key in users.keys():
        print key

    target = raw_input("Which user do you want to target? ").lower()

    while target not in users.keys():
        print "No such user was listed"

        for key in users.keys():
            print key

        target = raw_input("Which user do you want to target? ").lower()

    return users[target], target


target, username = target_user()
```

*This works and returns both values.*

I am assuming it is something to do with the fact the while loop does not call for the method again, but that does not explain why the "print" statement worked as expected.

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody would shed some light as to my illogic here.

Thank you.

Comment: Your first attempt works for me, Can you mention on which line you get error

Comment: For another issue, the data type you get from `raw_input` is string, which means `users[target]` would probably never get the result you want since `{ 1234 : 'username' }` where `1234` is int or some.

Comment: Your description doesn't make it clear whether the keys in the `users` dict are strings or ints; if they are ints then you'll need to convert the `target` string to int. Also, your recursive call in the `except` block should be `return target_user()`; however, as others have mentioned you don't need recursion for this (and in general it's a Good Idea to avoid recursion unless you really do need it).

Comment: @AlokThakur Thank you for testing my code. It is the very last line, where the function is actually called that I am given the error.

Comment: @Rick Thank you for replying, I have not encountered using string and integer data types as a problem for a single return, though I will stay mindful of it going forward.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Correct, I entered the key value pair the wrong way around, I will edit this now, thank you. Also, thank you for further speaking on the recursion, though I will continue to use it as it will just be myself and a handful of others running the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While other answerers are right that recursion is not really the right solution to your problem, the actual error you are getting is because you do not return the value from the recursive call. So, if the user ever types in a non-existent name, and the except clause calls the recursion, the only thing that is returned to the top level is None, which as the error says is not iterable. To fix this, just make sure you always return a value:

```
except KeyError:
    print "No such user was listed"

    return target_user()
```

But, again, recursion is not the way to solve this problem. Apart from anything else, a really perverse user could quite easily type in nonsense enough times to reach the maximum recursion depth, causing an error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation into why it was failing, and why the practise should be avoided. I am however going to continue using the recursion as this particular code will used only by about five or so people, with this recursive method only in place to assist in times when we have had more coffee than sleep... such as now.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake in the first version is that you tried to call the function again inside the function, which is recursion and not applicable to your problem. Try modifying it to handle the exception outside the function:

```
users = users_found()

def target_user():
    for key in users.keys():
        print key

    target = raw_input("Which user do you want to target? ").lower()

    try:
        print users[target], target
        return users[target], target
    except KeyError:
        print "No such user was listed"
        return None, None


target, username = None, None
while target is None:
    target, username = target_user()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and providing an example. When I develop something for general use this will likely be something I will look into using.